# Vercel Cron Job not updating my database using Prisma

Tags: next.js, cron, prisma, vercel

I'm using NextJS 13 and their new cron job feature. Im using a weather api to fetch data every 5 minutes and update my database in PlanetScale using Prisma.

I have set up a weather api as a serverless function like this at **src/api/weather/route.ts** :

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

const prisma = new PrismaClient();
const apiKey = process.env.WEATHER_API_KEY;

export async function GET() {
  try {
    const weatherData = await fetchWeatherData();
    await prisma.weatherCurrent.create({ data: weatherData });

    return new Response('Fetched correctly', {
      status: 200,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching weather data:', error);
  }
}

async function fetchWeatherData() {
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=${apiKey}&q=London`
  );
  const data = await response.json();
  const { location, current } = data;

  return {
    location: location,
    current: current,
  };
}
```

Next in my vercel.json file i set up the cron like this:

```
{
  "crons": [
    {
      "path": "/api/weather",
      "schedule": "*/5 * * * *"
    }
  ]
}
```

I do have a pro plan at vercel and I see the log and the cron job is being called every 5 minutes, but my database is not being updated. I can't find the error anywhere nor something in the documentation that could point what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue here, I have a next js 13 app deployed on **vercel** with prisma, and whenever i send a request to my databse using prisma it does not show the new data even if the request is successful. I found a solution which is to deploy the app on **netlify** and it worked perfectly fine

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was the cache vercel applied, I added `export const revalidate = 0` before the API function and it fixed the issue.